# How to capture dynamic code that's only temporally added to the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I am trying to debug a javascript application that temporally adds code to the HTML and then removes it after a couple of seconds. I typically use chrome's tools to look at the code, but the code is added and removed too fast for me to look at it. Is there a way to add breakpoints to the javascript? Or is there another way to capture the changes made to the HTML code?

Comment: Of course it has to use an element in the DOM, so just look for that element!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a [`debugger`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) line to the code; it will break the code there for inspection.

Comment: That should do it. Thank you!